# JS- textarea lines to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want save textarea lines in js array.
this code works but if we have empty line in textarea, array elements values set undefined after empty line!

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pYTjR/3/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function check(){
var lines = $('#links').val().split(/\n/);
var texts = []
for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {

  if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
    texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
    }
var links = texts;
var str = links[i];
alert(i+"-  "+str);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="links" name="upload" cols=80 rows=10>
www.example.com/book111.pdf
www.example.com/book222.pdf
www.example.com/book333.pdf

www.example.com/book444.pdf
www.example.com/book555.pdf
</textarea>

<input type="submit" id="getsize" name="getsize" value="textarea to array" onclick= "check()" />

</body>
</html>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pYTjR/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is functioning as you are expecting except not alerting correctly.  Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pYTjR/7/

```
function check(){
    var lines = $('#links').val().split(/\n/);
    var texts = [];
    for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
            texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
        }
    }
    for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        alert(i+"-  "+texts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about spliting with multiple parameters, like comma and line?

Comment: Change the split parameter regex to include a comma